# pure CSS dropdown not working properly

Tags: css

i tried making a simple css dropdown menu which is not working as expected.
the dropdown should appear when i hover the pointer on "menu1" .here is the link to the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F3Qg3/38/)
. Moreover i am bit frustrated with this piece of css code(i think this should be the code which will give me the desired output but why it is not working)

`#nav ul li:hover ul`

however if i replace it with

`#nav ul:hover ul`

it works but not as expected.

Comment: because your nested ul (for submenu) is not child of li but direct child of parent menu ul

Comment: you are right...i did not notice it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the sub menus inside the parent li:

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">menu0</a></li>
        <li class="main">
            <a href="">menu1</a>
            <ul>
                <li class="sub"><a href="">menu2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/F3Qg3/39/

Answer (score 1):

Just add `>` in your code as follows:

```
#nav ul li:hover ul
```

Change into:

```
#nav ul > li:hover ul
```

When you would like to create sub menu, the structure should be like this:

```
<li><a href="#">parent-menu</a></li>
<li><a href="#">parent-dropdown-menu</a>
    <ul>
        <li>........</li> <!--child-->
    </ul>
</li>
```

See the little changes here: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Alicera/zj8krh95/)**